# centos7 repartition issue

Tags: centos

I need to give more space to `centos-root` from `centos-home`.

I umounted /home, after

```
lvremove /dev/mapper/centos-home
```

then,

```
lvextend -L 500G /dev/mapper/centos-root
```

and final

```
mount /home
```

The issue is that now the `ls` command from `/home` gives me:

```
ls: cannot open directory .: Input/output error.
```

I have already tried with `xfs_repair /dev/mapper/centos-home`, but the result is `xfs_repair: cannot open /dev/mapper/centos-home: Device or resource busy`

Any other ideas. I don't want to reinstall the operating system.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you remember to reduce the size of the filesystem before reducing the LV it's on?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I forgot to say that.

Comment: I found something weird:   df -h
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/centos-root  500G   50G  451G  10% /
devtmpfs                  16G     0   16G   0% /dev
tmpfs                     16G     0   16G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                     16G  1.7G   15G  11% /run
tmpfs                     16G     0   16G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2               1014M  172M  843M  17% /boot
/dev/sda1                200M  9.8M  191M   5% /boot/efi
/dev/mapper/centos-home  1.8T   33M  1.8T   1% /home
tmpfs                    3.2G     0  3.2G   0% /run/user/1000

Comment: where did you mount /home to ? (after you lvremoved it previous LV?). Also, the lvextend on root LV will not extend the file-system without -r option (you did not mention it).

Comment: the fdisk -l
Disk /dev/mapper/centos-home: 859.0 GB, 858993459200 bytes, 1677721600 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Comment: the \home is like this: [root@neptune /]# ls -l
ls: cannot access home: Input/output error
total 72
lrwxrwxrwx.   1 root root      7 May 11 06:23 bin -> usr/bin
dr-xr-xr-x.   5 root root   4096 May 11 06:58 boot
drwxr-xr-x.  20 root root   3320 May 16 04:56 dev
drwxr-xr-x.  79 root root   8192 May 23 04:02 etc
d??????????   ? ?    ?         ?            ? home
lrwxrwxrwx.   1 root root      7 May 11 06:23 lib -> usr/lib
lrwxrwxrwx.   1 root root      9 May 11 06:23 lib64 -> usr/lib64

Comment: Please [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/445550/edit) your post with the info you've given in these comments.

Answer (score 0):

Check the filesystem :

```
e2fsck -f /dev/mapper/vg_livecd-lv_home
```

better do `resize` /home rather than `remove`

Follow the steps:

```
Step:1 Umount the file system
# umount /home/

Step:2 check the file system for Errors using e2fsck command.
# e2fsck -f /dev/mapper/vg_livecd-lv_home

Step:3 Reduce or Shrink the size of /home to required size.
# resize2fs /dev/mapper/vg_livecd-lv_home 50G

Step:4 Reduce the size using lvreduce command.
# lvreduce -L 50G /dev/mapper/vg_livecd-lv_home 

Step:5 Check the filesystem before mount
# e2fsck -f /dev/mapper/vg_livecd-lv_home

Step:6 Mount the file system and verify its size.
# mount /home
```

-> Steps to increase LVM:

```
Step1: Check the free available space in the Volume group
#  vgdisplay < Volume-Group-Name>

Step2: Increase the size using Lvextend command
# lvextend -L +120G /dev/mapper/vg_livecd-lv_root

Step:3 Run the resize2fs command
# resize2fs /dev/mapper/vg_livecd-lv_root 

Step:4 Verify Size
# df -Th
```